How to pin items in DropDown List Bootstrap?
I am using the latest version of Bootstrap as of 2024 and I have this dropdown menu of the most recent items. I want the user to have the ability to pin items in this menu so that they won't get over-written by new most recent items that enter the list. I probably will add a flag in the DB that will check but I couldn't find an example of anyone implementing this.

What have you tried so far? SO isn't a code-writing service.

@mykaf I just have a basic Dropdown List from a bootstrap example. I was figuring out a way to display a pin and then keep it at the dropdown list.
